# Subscribe an observable only if a certain property changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

I need rxjs's `subscribe` method to be restricted to certain property changes. I tried to do it with `distinctUntilChanged` but I think I am missing something.

I only want subscribe to fire, when the property `data.members[]` changed.

```
this.myService.loadData(this.data.id)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    console.log("data changed", data);
});
```

How can I react to distinct changes?

Comment: Do you it to react to distinct changes to the `data.members` property **reference** value? Or distinct changes to the **contents** of the array to which the `data.members` property refers?

Comment: i want to react to changes within the array (item added / deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation (Rxjs v4)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md), I see that you should be able to achieve what you want, with `Rx.Observable.prototype.distinctUntilChanged([keySelector], [comparer])`, and using the `keySelector` to select the property whose changes you want to detect, and `comparer` parameter to detect equality.

Rxjs v5 has [distinctUntilKeyChanged](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/distinctUntilKeyChanged.ts) and [distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/distinctUntilChanged.ts) with similar features.

You can have a look at the tests for example of usage : [https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/distinctUntilChanged-spec.ts, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged-spec.ts]

I guess from that you should be able to set something up, if not, post back what you tried.

Comment: `.distinctUntilChanged((data) => { return data.members; })` works! How could I check for multiple arrays? (members, relations, children) ?

Answer (score 0):

> `.distinctUntilChanged((data) => { return data.members; })` works! How could I check for multiple arrays? (members, relations, children) ?
>
> i want to react to changes within the array (item added / deleted).

Use `angular.equals` to do deep compare.

```
this.myService.loadData(this.data.id)
  .distinctUntilChanged((data) => (data.members), (a,b) => (angular.equals(a,b))
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    console.log("data changed", data);
});
```

For more information on `distinctUntilChanged`, see [RxJS distinctUntilChanged API Reference](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md).

For more information on `angular.equals`, see [AngularJS angular.equals API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals).